# How to add angular js module inside an existing application

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, directive

I am trying to add an angular JS module inside an already existing code. I'm actually trying to add a new piece of code inside it. The workflow goes like this. When a button is clicked, the JS takes a template and adds it to the dom. In this added template, i would like to insert the new angular JS module. I am trying to atleast show hello world inside the module but haven't been successful.

Let's say when a button is clicked, i'm adding the below tag to the dom

```
<div patient-details ng-controller='patientDetailsCtrl' id='patientDetails'></div>
```

This is added through jquery or javascript. How do i make it work with the below directive

```
angular.module('patientDetailsModule',[])
.directive('patientDetails',function($compile){
    return{
        //restrict: 'E',
        template: "<div>Hello World!!!{{name}}</div>"
    };
});
```

Comment: I did not understand :(. Could you explain?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use $compile.  $compile() will make sure all the Angular code in your html snippet will be *compiled!*

Here is an example.

http://plnkr.co/edit/7Wr3oAtvZ8cn31uFFEOs?p=preview

- Send Message from nc-click to directive
- Directive receives message, compiles html and appends new element

  ```
              var template = "<div patient-details ng-controller='patientDetailsCtrl' id='patientDetails'>Element added</div>";
              var newElement = angular.element(template);
              $compile(newElement)(scope);
              element.append(newElement);
              // can also use element.replaceWith(newElement);
  ```